# Spring mvc - view ms office files,pdf and images from DB

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Can someone help me to find a way to allow the users to view the files in a browser when they click on a link?

I want this feature to be implemented in a web application, I use Spring MVC and Hibernate. I have my files stored in a database and I want them to be viewed in a browser.

Is it possible in any way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly You need to use pdf, office etc. apis to create documents. If browser supports inner window display, you can call the documents from a specific path and display them to user.

Comment: Thanks @TugrulAsik . Let me give a shot at this.

Comment: Check this topics; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118635/what-is-the-best-pdf-open-source-library-for-java   , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156915/good-way-to-create-pdf-from-office-documents-in-java/156946#156946 , http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/